# Error on updating collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, var

I have a database in MongoDB with two collections x and y. I am trying to update the field x.Venue  = y.name where x.club = y.team.
I tried th following code in mongoDB.

```
db.x.find().forEach(function(myDoc) {
       var temp = db.y.findOne({"team" : myDoc.club});
       if (temp) {
             myDoc.Venue = temp.name;
             db.x.save(myDoc);
        }
 });
```

Now, correct me if i am wrong, the myDoc varibale is the cursor for the forEach function.i verified that the temp data is correct and myDoc.Venue is correctly being assigned . Though, i get the following error.

```
2016-07-01T23:43:58.382+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error: {
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "cannot compare to undefined",
    "code" : 2
} :

_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCommandCursor@src/mongo/shell/query.js:689:1
DBQuery.prototype._exec@src/mongo/shell/query.js:118:28
DBQuery.prototype.hasNext@src/mongo/shell/query.js:276:5
DBCollection.prototype.findOne@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:289:10
@(shell):1:61
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:488:1
@(shell):1:1
```

Could anyone help me out to fix this error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was facing same type of problem and solved. This error happened when you want to compare db **property/field** with **undefined**. so you should check first before compare.

when compared `{"team" : myDoc.club}` in your query where as `myDoc.club` is `undefined` so this error occurred.

so can try this one

```
db.x.find().forEach(function(myDoc) {
       if(myDoc.club){
           var temp = db.y.findOne({"team" : myDoc.club});
           if (temp) {
              myDoc.Venue = temp.name;
              db.x.save(myDoc);
           }
       }
 });
```